# Manual normalization function taking too long to execute

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, normalizing

I am trying to implement a normalization function manually rather than using the scikit learn's one. The reason is that, I need to define the maximum and minimum parameters manually and scikit learn doesn't allow that alteration.

I successfully implemented this to normalize the values between 0 and 1. But it is taking a very long time to run.

**Question:** **Is there another efficient way I can do this? How can I make this execute faster.**

Shown below is my code:

```
scaled_train_data = scale(train_data)

def scale(data):
    for index, row in data.iterrows():
        X_std = (data.loc[index, "Close"] - 10) / (2000 - 10)
        data.loc[index, "Close"] = X_std

    return data
```

2000 and 10 are the attributes that i defined manually rather than taking the minimum and the maximum value of the dataset.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why loop? You can just use

```
train_data['close'] = (train_data['close'] - 10)/(2000 - 10)
```

to make use of vectorized numpy functions. Of course, you could also put this in a function, if you prefer.

Alternatively, if you want to rescale to a linear range, you could use http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html. The advantage of this is that you can save it and then rescale the test data in the same manner.

Comment: Thank you it worked. The problem with the MinMAxScaler is that i don't want to get the minimum and the maximum in the data column. I want to put a manual generalized value. scikit learn automatically takes the minimum and the maximum of the column and normalizes it. Correct me if I'm wrong. That's why i thought of doing this manually

Comment: Well, you can add the range you want to scale to, for instance: `sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 3))`. I don't know how you chose the numbers 2000 and 10, but if you chose them to scale to a particular range, you can use this option. It's true, to my knowledge, you cannot input those (probably because it is already a one-liner like above).

Answer (score 2):

Use numpy's matrix.you can also set your min and max mannually.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(df)
_min = np.min(data, axis=0)
_max = np.max(data, axis=0)
normed_data = (data - _min) / (_max - _min)
```

Comment: for loop and calculate X_std of each column separately  makes it takes a very long time.